# Why NOT IN (NULL) Always returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table:
[image: My Table]
And following simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Calendars WHERE calname NOT IN(NULL)
```

My question is why always **NOT IN(NULL)** return nothing?
**PS**:No matter what is your table,if you add **NOT IN(NULL)** to *any* column's condition,result is nothing.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: try calname is not null

Comment: Thank you @Sachu .That works for me.but I'm searching for scenario behind NOT IN and why this doesn't work in this way

Comment: Null is an unknoen value, and as such is niether equall nor different form any value, including another null. So `null = null` is false and `null  <> null` is also false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because  `value equals NULL` is not defined, and will never evaluate to True.
Check [This post on bad practices](http://www.sqlbadpractices.com/using-not-in-operator-with-null-values/). Don't use `IN` and `NULL`, use `EXISTS` to test for at least one row where something exists.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is treated differently to other values in most databases.  For instance, this predicate will never be true:

```
WHERE foo = NULL
```

whereas this predicate is true if the value of `foo` is indeed `NULL`:

```
WHERE foo IS NULL
```

---

To your problem, if you only wish to check if `calname` is not null, use the following predicate:

```
WHERE calname IS NOT NULL
```

If on the other hand you have a set of values, of which `NULL` is one of those values (say [1,2,3,4,NULL]), and you still want to use the `NOT IN` syntax, you have to do it like this:

```
WHERE calname IS NOT NULL AND calname NOT IN(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

---

EDIT: A further way of doing this, if you are constrained to use the `NOT IN` syntax is to `COALESCE` the column `calname` into a value that you definitely know is not stored in that column.  For instance, if `calname` can only take positive integer values, then we can do this instead:

```
WHERE COALESCE(calname, -1) NOT IN (-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query evaluates to calname <> null , which results in UNKNOWN.

Change your query to this ,

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Calendars WHERE calname IS NOT NULL;
```